# Error when aggregating due to conversion from varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

**Situation:**

I want to aggregate a value from a table but i get the following error :

> Error converting data type varchar to big int.

I've been reading countless of different solutions online but they don't seem to solve it.

**Current query;**
So based on the error message, i simply added the CAST function but it still doesnt work.

```
SELECT
    base.target_date AS target_date
  , base.game_id AS game_id                                                                                                 
  , base.device AS device
  , ISNULL(CAST(SUM(use_point.point) AS bigint),0) AS result                     
FROM 
    cte AS base

LEFT JOIN cte2 AS use_point         
    ON base.target_date = use_point.target_date 
    AND base.game_id = use_point.device
    AND base.device = use_point.device

GROUP BY
    base.target_date 
  , base.device 
  , base.game_id
WITH ROLLUP
GO
```

Comment: `AND base.game_id = use_point.device`... this looks wrong to me!

Comment: Apparently `device` column is a varchar and comparing it with an int generates the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming that `use_point.point` is a `VARCHAR`, in which case simply change where you put your `CAST` statement:

```
, ISNULL(SUM(CAST(use_point.point AS bigint)), 0) AS result
```

Note that the `CAST` now takes place before the `SUM`.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg I would presume that the problem may be with the `JOIN` in that case.  Are all of the join columns the same data type?

Comment: Is there a quick way to find that out?

Comment: This would even fix the problem, if `point` were a string.  I'm baffled by the upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRY_CAST()` instead.  And it needs to be an argument to the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT base.target_date, base.game_id, base.device,
       COALESCE(SUM(TRY_CAST(use_point.point as bigint)), 0) as result
FROM . . .
```

Note that your column aliases are redundant, because you are assigning the default aliases.

You should also fix the data.  Don't store numeric values as strings.  To find the bad data, you can use:

```
select points
from use_points
where try_convert(points as bigint) is null and
      points is not null;
```

Comment: whats the difference between try cast and cast in this case? and why coalesce instead of isnul?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . `TRY_CAST()` returns `NULL` when the conversion fails, which will solve your immediate problem.  `COALESCE()` is a SQL standard function.  `ISNULL()` is a bespoke SQL Server function.  I prefer standard SQL functions as a general rule.

Comment: but my column point is int in the db... thats why im confused with that error message. i tried your answer and it doesnt work.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . The problem is probably then happening on the `JOIN` comparisons.  They do look suspicious.